# Setting a div tag's innerHTML to a string returns an unspecified error

Tags: javascript, html

So, just for fun, my friend and I are working on developing a cheat for [this game](http://www.decisionproblem.com/paperclips/index2.html), which has gone viral recently. The website already has cheat buttons hidden in a comment tag. I am attempting to add the cheat buttons into the page using Javascript. Here's what I have so far:

```js
var tt=document.createElement('div');
tt.setAttribute('id', 'CMenu');
var g=document.getElementById('adCost');
var RAW='<button id ="save1Button" onclick=\"save1()\">SAVE SLOT 1</button>' +
'<button id ="load1Button" onclick="load1()">LOAD SLOT 1</button>' +
'<button id ="save2Button" onclick="save2()">SAVE SLOT 2</button>' +
'<button id ="load2Button" onclick="load2()">LOAD SLOT 2</button>' +
'<button id ="resetButton" onclick="reset()">RESET ALL PROGRESS</button>' +
'<button id ="freeClipsButton" onclick="cheatClips()">Free Clips</button>' +
'<button id ="freeMoneyButton" onclick="cheatMoney()">Free Money</button>' +
'<button id ="freeTrustButton" onclick="cheatTrust()">Free Trust</button>' +
'<button id ="freeOpsButton" onclick="cheatOps()">Free Ops</button>' +
'<button id ="freeCreatButton" onclick="cheatCreat()">Free Creativity</button>' +
'<button id ="freeYomiButton" onclick="cheatYomi()">Free Yomi</button>' +
'<button id ="resetPrestige" onclick="resetPrestige()">Reset Prestige</button>' +
'<button id ="destroyAllHumansButton" onclick="cheatHypno()">Destroy all Humans</button>' +
'<button id ="freePrestigeU" onclick="cheatPrestigeU()">Free Prestige U</button>' +
'<button id ="freePrestigeS" onclick="cheatPrestigeS()">Free Prestige S</button>' +
'<button id ="debugBattleNumbers" onclick="setB()">Set Battle Number 1 to 7</button>' +
'<button id ="availMatterZero" onclick="zeroMatter()">Set Avail Matter to 0</button>';
document.getElementById('CMenu').innerHTML= RAW
g.appendChild(tt);
```

When I run the final line I get an unspecified error.

[image: example]

There is no indentation because it is going to be run as a Javascript bookmark. I cannot use inspect element nor the console in the scenario in which I will execute it.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include the error message.

Comment: That isn't an error. It just shows the new contents of the `.innerHTML` property.

Comment: There was no error given. It just shows up red and does nothing :/

Comment: `document.getElementById('CMenu')`, you can't get an element by ID if the element with that id is not in the document (ie you haven't added `tt` to the document yet). Just use `tt.innerHTML`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I guess that's just an error in the code sample here at Stack Overflow as the question doesn't include any markup.

Comment: @agrm, they are creating the element at the very top of their code, and don't append it till the very end

Comment: @PatrickEvans Not `g`...

Comment: @agrm what about g? I am talking about `tt`. They set it to a newly created element, then give it an id of `CMenu` then try to query the document looking for an element with that id. But since they have not added it to the document, it isn't going to be found

Comment: @PatrickEvans My mistake, I misread your first comment. I thought you were commenting on the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" appearing when running the code snippet. Which was thrown when running `g.appendChild(tt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing isn't an error, it's just the browser printing out the `.innerHTML` that you set.

This is happening because you're running your code in the console which intentionally gives you more feedback. If you run it in a bookmarklet or a script it won't display.

However, you do have a bug in your code. You create your `tt` element, give it an ID of `CMenu` but before you append it to the document, you try to get it by it's ID, but it isn't in the document yet.

The solution is to either add the element to the document before trying to get it by ID, or a much better approach, simply refer to your existing `tt` variable.

```
var tt = document.createElement('div');
tt.id = 'CMenu'; // set id property directly, no need for setAttribute
var raw = '...';
tt.innerHTML = raw ; // reuse the reference you already have
g.appendChild(tt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the cheat menu on [the game](http://www.decisionproblem.com/paperclips/index2.html) by making a bookmarklet with this for the location:

```js
javascript:var tt=document.createElement('div');
tt.setAttribute('id', 'CMenu');
var g=document.getElementById('adCost');
var RAW='<button id ="save1Button" onclick=\"save1()\">SAVE SLOT 1</button>' +
'<button id ="load1Button" onclick="load1()">LOAD SLOT 1</button>' +
'<button id ="save2Button" onclick="save2()">SAVE SLOT 2</button>' +
'<button id ="load2Button" onclick="load2()">LOAD SLOT 2</button>' +
'<button id ="resetButton" onclick="reset()">RESET ALL PROGRESS</button>' +
'<button id ="freeClipsButton" onclick="cheatClips()">Free Clips</button>' +
'<button id ="freeMoneyButton" onclick="cheatMoney()">Free Money</button>' +
'<button id ="freeTrustButton" onclick="cheatTrust()">Free Trust</button>' +
'<button id ="freeOpsButton" onclick="cheatOps()">Free Ops</button>' +
'<button id ="freeCreatButton" onclick="cheatCreat()">Free Creativity</button>' +
'<button id ="freeYomiButton" onclick="cheatYomi()">Free Yomi</button>' +
'<button id ="resetPrestige" onclick="resetPrestige()">Reset Prestige</button>' +
'<button id ="destroyAllHumansButton" onclick="cheatHypno()">Destroy all Humans</button>' +
'<button id ="freePrestigeU" onclick="cheatPrestigeU()">Free Prestige U</button>' +
'<button id ="freePrestigeS" onclick="cheatPrestigeS()">Free Prestige S</button>' +
'<button id ="debugBattleNumbers" onclick="setB()">Set Battle Number 1 to 7</button>' +
'<button id ="availMatterZero" onclick="zeroMatter()">Set Avail Matter to 0</button>';
g.appendChild(tt);
document.getElementById('CMenu').innerHTML= RAW
```

Comment: Please don't use answers as replies, use the comments. I removed the message for you.

Comment: Sorry. This was literally my first question. I just made my account.